# Write a program to find the second longest word without using array

Tags: java

I need a java program to find the second-longest word in a sentence (without using an array).

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
class Second_longest_Trial {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
    String s = in .readLine();
    s = s.trim() + " ";
    String longest = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' '));
    String sec = longest;
    int l = s.length();
    String temp = " ", str = " ";

    for (int i = s.indexOf(' ') + 1; i < l; i++) {
      char ch = s.charAt(i);

      if (ch != ' ')
        temp = temp + ch;
      else {
        if (temp.length() > longest.length()) {
          sec = longest;
          longest = temp;
        } else if (temp.length() > sec.length()) {
          sec = temp;
        }
        temp = " ";
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Longest word is " + longest);
    System.out.println("Second Longest word is " + sec);
  }
}
```

When I am giving the input-

> Sayan goes home.

This outputs-

> Longest word is Sayan
> Second Longest word is Sayan

I should have got the output as follows-

> Longest word is Sayan
> Second Longest word is goes

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You are going to get lots of downvotes this way. We are not here to do your homework.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Dumping your assignments on us is not asking a good question.

Comment: Hire a freelancer, we are not a codefactory.

Comment: Ouch, I think adding "as soon as possible" easily has doubled the number of downvotes you have to expect.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) as well as [this article](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) on why you can't (and shouldn't) ask this kind of question here.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's wrong with what you have right now?

Answer (score 1):

Drop your wonky initial setting of `longest` and `sec`. Create them and `temp` the following way:

```
String longest="";
String sec="";
String temp="";

for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    ...
```

Why would you set `longest` and `sec` both to the first word - guess what happens if that first word is the longest in the sentence?

Then your code produces the output:

> Longest word is Sayan
>   Second Longest word is home.

That is more correct than what you currently have but still not what you would expect ... because there is the `.` at the end of the sentence you have to take care of - maybe make the check for `ch!=' '` a bit more complex and check against `'.'` as well. I leave it for you to figure out how to do that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have initialized the longest element as first word and sec also as longest(which is **Sayan** itself). Now longest = "Sayan" and sec = "Sayan", you went inside the array but you never found any word which is bigger than longest or sec.

Answer (score 0):

```
To find the Second Largest Word Try the Below, I used the TreeMap which will sort in the natural order of the key

   

    public class FindSecondLargest {
    Map<Integer,String> map;
    public String getSecondLargest(String[] testarr) {
        int length= testarr.length;
        map=new TreeMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            map.put(testarr[i].length(),testarr[i]);
        }
        int i=0;
        String result="";
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> entry = map.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, String>itr:entry)
        {
            if(i==length-2) {
                result = itr.getValue();
                break;
            }
            else i++;

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very basic code to find the second longest word:

```
       class Second
       {
            public static void main(String str)//str has the required sentence
            {
                String m="",q="";
                int lar=0;
                str=str+" ";
                for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
                {
                    for(int k=0;k<str.length();k++)
                    {
                       char ch=str.charAt(k);
                       if(ch!=' ')
                       m=m+ch;
                       else
                       {
                           if(m.length()>lar)
                           {
                              q=m;
                              lar=q.length();
                           }
                           m="";
                       }
                     }
                     if(i==1)
                     {
                        System.out.println("The longest word is: "+q);
                        str=str.replace(q," ");
                        lar=0;
                     }
                }
                System.out.println("The second longest word is: "+q);
             }
       }
```

Comment: I suggest you add in comments (`// This does x, y, and z`) to explain to the asker what everything is doing